# Solver for sparse linearly-constrained non-linear least-squares

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra, nonlinear-optimization

Reposted from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16533810/solver-for-sparse-linearly-constrained-non-linear-least-squares) on the advice of [Nick Rosencrantz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/108207/nick-rosencrantz):

Are there any algorithms or solvers for solving non-linear least-squares problems where the jacobian is known to always be sparse, and the solution is constrained with either:

1. Linear equality constraints and box constraints
2. General linear inequality constraints

Comment: I hate do do this to you since you've already moved this once, but you would be much better served asking this on the [CompSci SE](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com).